# Serverside protection mechanism to prevent anyone viewing javascript source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

I know you can use a javascript obfuscator to make javascript source protected, but I need a better solution on top of this.

I'm investigating options to encrypt a javascript file to be placed on some websites. This javascript file is included on the page in a script tag like normal, i.e.:

```html
<script src="http://secure.com/encryted.js"></script>
```

The idea is to somehow prevent users viewing the source of the javascript or at least make it much harder to do so...

I'm thinking of a way to only return the javascript by doing something like

```html
<script src="http://secure.com/validate.php"></script>
```

That way I could on the host secure.com check for certain conditions and only return the javascript (encrypted) if those conditions are met.

Does anyone have an idea or done such a thing? Or knows of good way to prevent sourcecode of javascript to be exposed or make it very hard?

ETA seems a good way to encrypt it: http://www.enetplanet.com/enc/

My goal is to have people viewing the source /html not be able to "just view" the source

Any thoughts?

Comment: This might sound rude (not my intention), but have you used Google? The only thing you can expect for *answers* are just bunch of links to online *JS uglyfiers* (if that's the term you're looking for ;)

Comment: Not possible at all. The browser has to be able to read the JS (and the HTML, and the CSS, and more things). The browser is running on the user's computer, and *will* happily present the source code to the user if she asks.

Comment: Yes javascript obfosculator seems the only solution I found. Ive updated question a bit to be more clear; making a serverside check to  prevent the code getting delivered to the client

Comment: Don't want people to see your code? Then use server side code exclusively. Make calls into a server side service that does the work of your script and then use something like echo or response.write to return the html.

Comment: Obfuscation is probably your best bet; make it so a human has a hard understanding how your code works. Having the browser *encrypt* something to hide it *from the user* is doomed from the start, since any moderately skilled user can find the encryption subroutine and grab the key (either manually on the JS console or automatically by making a simple browser extension). You must assume two foolish things: 1) the browser can do something that the user can't undo and 2) the browser is trustworthy and hasn't been modified with user extensions.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times. Bottom line is, **you cannot hide your client side javascript**.

Comment: If you don't deliver the code to the client, it can't execute on the client side. If you want it to execute on the client, you have to deliver it. You're asking how to deliver a package without giving the recipient what's in the package.

Comment: this question shows  a complete lack of research effort

Comment: JavaScript is a client-side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TEA (http://www.enetplanet.com/enc/) is not the kind of tool you can use for such a task. It is just a little bit more than a proof-of-concept or than a toy. TEA (like any other encryption system) cannot be actually used to encrypt/protect a javascript file that you send to the customer's browser.

Consider this: the user must have a copy of the encryption program to decypher the javascript file coming from your server. In other cases, this would not be a great security hole in itself. Any encryption system rely on the secretness of a key, not on the secreteness of the encryption program/algorithm.

Unfortunately, when talking of client-side javascript, this *is* a security hole. The encryption program (TEA) is a javascript file itself. Anybody can read it. It is trivial to modify it in a way that it just print out the encryption key or in a way that it just decrypt the "protected" javascript file without making any check.

Moreover, the end-user has total, unlimited access to the network comunication channel. He can just read the password (the key) with a network sniffer installed on its PC. No key (and no encryption system) can resist such an attack (well-known as a "man-in-the-middle" attack).

It is well known that there isn't any real way to encrypt/protect a javascript file. The best you can do is to obfuscate it.

If you really need to protect some kind of client-side software, you have to use *compiled software* (C/C++), *encryption* and some kind of *hardware key*. Any other system can easily be "cracked" (as the whole history of computer games can demonstrate).